# JSP Duas casas após a vírgula

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho o seguinte número: 10.205203
Gostaria que fosse exibido em apenas 10,02;

Tenho essa função, não sei se é a certa

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${media / total}" pattern="#,#0.0#" />
```

Agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar `minFractionDigits` e `maxFractionDigits` - [referência](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html).

```xml
<fmt:formatNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${media / total}"/>
```

Comment: legal! Deu certo